# How to run mitmproxy in Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, mitmproxy

I am using mitmproxy with Python. Python version is 3.11.0 and mitmproxy version is 10.2.0. When I install mitmproxy, it installed other dependencies such as

```
mitmproxy-macos==0.5.1
mitmproxy_rs==0.5.1
urwid-mitmproxy==2.1.2.1
```

When I run in my local environment, it works fine but when I tried to run in Heroku, it returns an error. The error looks like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/mitmdump", line 5, in <module>
     from mitmproxy.tools.main import mitmdump 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module name 'mitmproxy.tools'
```

When I check build log in Heroku, the package is installed properly with same version that I have in my local environment.

After running Python main File, I am running mitmproxy as follows:

```
subprocess.Popen(['mitmdump', '-s', 'filepath'])
```

Comment: You can try to directly execute mitmdump without using the executable:  `python -c "from mitmproxy.tools.main import *; mitmdump(['-p 8123'])"`

Comment: @Robert Would you mind explaining what you did? What is this about `mitmdump(['-p 8123'])`

Comment: That is just an example showing you how to send command-line arguments to the mitmdump instance (e.g. start on port 8123). In `mitmproxy.tools.main` `mitmdump` is just a function that is called with the cmd-line arguments as parameter (array of string).

Comment: @Robert I am trying to use mitmproxy with selenium using this example https://scrapfly.io/blog/how-to-block-resources-in-selenium/